# Migrating server with separate registrar - update dns in registar or hosting/cpanel account?

Tags: domain, dns-zone, domain-registrar

I am moving a website to a new server, the domain is registered with a separate registrar

Another guy owns the registrar account and has added the new nameservers for me, I have updated DNS settings on the hosting account

Am I right in thinking I need to ask the owner of the domain to update the dns settings in the registrar account too?

Email is hosted by the server, and the domain is registered not on the hosting site (so a separate registrar and hosting account)

Apologies for the stupid question

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: The only records that matter are the ones on the nameservers configured for the domain.

Comment: Thanks, so I do not need to get the domain owner to update any dns settings such as cname, a record etc? They are all fine in the dns zone on the hosting, but I noticed when I do a crawl on SEO software Semrush, it says there was an error crawling due to DNS configuration. I thought I must have missed something when moving to our new hosting site. Have used DNS checkers which don't seem to show any major issues

Comment: You should give us the domain in question. Your description is fairly confusing, and I'd hesitate to say what you should do given that I'm having trouble deciphering what you *have* done.

Comment: the other owner doesn't want it posted sorry! A standard wordpress website, old host got rid of his hosting, so I set them up a hosting account. Simply asking if I need to update any dns settings other than the new nameservers (which we did a week or so ago so have taken effect now) in the registrar account. Is it that confusing? I am a web designer but don't deal much in hosting, sorry!

Comment: Figure out which nameservers are defined at the registrar. Make sure those nameservers have the correct records. To help debug beyond that, we'll need the domain.

Comment: I think you are confused, sorry, nameservers are fine, our new ones have been added. Do I need to edit any DNS settings at registrar other than the nameservers? I am guessing from your response the nameservers are all that matter

Comment: Again, only the nameservers you've defined as the primary nameservers for that domain at the registrar level matter. It doesn't matter if the registrar offers their own nameservers *if you're not using them*.

Comment: We have had *quite* a few people who *thought* they'd configured things correctly, but hadn't. That's why we ask for the domain, and why we hesitate to say "yep you're good" when it's not provided.

Comment: thanks but no issue with nameservers, we successfuly added the new ones, I am asking about records, cnames, mx records etc

Comment: I'm not sure where the disconnect is here. Records exist on a nameserver. You only need records on the nameservers responsible for serving your domain. I can put your records on *my* nameservers but it won't *do* anything, because no one looks there for them. Figure out *which* nameservers are responsible for your domain, and configure them accordingly with the right records. I'm done here unless you'd like to provide the domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's absolutely no technical reason to change the Name Servers simply because the website is moving.
2. `"Another guy owns the registrar account and has added the new nameservers for me, I have updated DNS settings on the hosting account."` What does that mean, exactly? Does that mean that the new web hosting provider is also hosting the DNS zone?
3. Assuming the answer to item 2 is Yes, then the answer is no, you don't need to do anything more at the Registrar.
4. Telling us the actual domain name would go a long way in helping us give you better answers.

Comment: No, like I said I have the hosting account but the domain is with someone else, simply asking if the DNS settings on the domain account need updating (cname, mx record etc). There is a DNS zone on the cpanel in the hosting account which I have access to. I am asking if anything other than nameservers need updating in the domain registrar account. And yes of coarse the nameservers need updating as they have changed, the old host has closed down, we pointed the site at the new hosting account. i.e changed from ns1.oldnameservers.co.uk, ns2.oldnameservers.co.uk to ns1.newnameservers.co.uk etc